# Inheriting operator +()

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

How to inherit overloaded operator +()?

For example, I have two classes:

```
class Bin : public Number<2, 256>
{
public:
    Bin(const char* number = NULL) :
        Number(number)
    {}
};
```

and

```
template <unsigned int BASE, unsigned int ORDER>
class Number
{
private:
    ...

public:
    Number(const char* number = NULL) {
        ...
    }

    const Number& operator +=(const Number& number) {
        ...
    }

    Number operator +(const Number& number) const {
        Number result = *this;
        return result += number;
    }
};
```

operator +() returns Number. But I want to do:

```
Bin firstNum("101010111010");
Bin secondNum("1101011101");
Bin result = firstNum + secondNum;
```

Type of (firstNum + secondNum) - Number<2, 256> not Bin. Must I overload +() in every inheritor?

Comment: Note that this problem is not specific to `operator+`, or even operators in general.  It's true for "normal" member functions as well...

Answer (score 1):

Consider what would need to happen in a slightly more complicated example than yours, where the derived class `Bin` has its own member variables.  How could the base-class function possibly know what to do in order to create the return value?  And what would it do in "mixed-mode" additions?  (e.g. if one argument was a `Bin`, and the other was a `Blah`).

So yes, you will need to define specific operators everywhere that you want specific behaviour.  Note that this is true not just of overloaded operators, but member functions in general.

Comment: If I want to define own add operator for every derived class I must copy code. How to resolve that problem more clear?

Comment: Lots of good documentation. To be more clear, like what Oli was saying, what happens if you do this: define a Hex class, then add Bin plus Hex? Number doesn't know anything about either class, so you have to decide what to do in the derived class: do you return a Bin? a Hex? Throw an error? You can still wrap and use the implementation in Number, but ultimately, you will _need_ code in the derived classes to resolve this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to just duplicate the implementation for `operator+` in all derived classes.  However, if you're feeling adventurous you could use the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to enforce type consistency in your `Number` template class.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done, operators can't be made to be virtual(i.e. inherited).  NOT directly at least.

You can do this:

```
class Base {
public:
   Base operator+(const Base& addend) { return addOp(addend) ; }
private:
   virtual Base addOp(const Base& addend) ;
} ;
```

and then override addOp to your heart's content.  However you NEED to make sure that anything that inherits can return a 'Base' that will work with anything else.  This gets to be pretty complicated pretty fast.

Comment: That might be slightly confusing, when adding two derived classes results in a `Base`.